# Triplet model for image retrieval from the Keras pretrained network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to implement a model for image retrieval. The model will be trained with a triplet loss function (same as facenet or similar architectures). My idea was to use a pretrained classification model from Keras (e.g. resnet50), and make it a triple architecture. This is my model in Keras:

```
resnet_input = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top = False, input_tensor=resnet_input)
net = resnet_model.output

net = Flatten(name='flatten')(net) 
net = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='embded')(net)
net = Lambda(l2Norm, output_shape=[512])(net)

base_model = Model(resnet_model.input, net, name='resnet_model')

input_shape=(224,224,3)
input_anchor = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_anchor')
input_positive = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_pos')
input_negative = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_neg')

net_anchor = base_model(input_anchor)
net_positive = base_model(input_positive)
net_negative = base_model(input_negative)

positive_dist = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name='pos_dist')([net_anchor, net_positive])
negative_dist = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name='neg_dist')([net_anchor, net_negative])

stacked_dists = Lambda( 
            lambda vects: K.stack(vects, axis=1),
            name='stacked_dists'
)([positive_dist, negative_dist])

model = Model([input_anchor, input_positive, input_negative], stacked_dists, name='triple_siamese')

def triplet_loss(_, y_pred):
    margin = K.constant(1)
    return K.mean(K.maximum(K.constant(0), K.square(y_pred[0]) - K.square(y_pred[1]) + margin))

def accuracy(_, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred[0] < y_pred[1])

def l2Norm(x):
    return  K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)

def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True), K.epsilon()))
```

The model should predict a feature vector for every image. The distances (euclidean in this case) between these vectors should be close to zero if the images are from the same class, or close to one if they're not.

I already tried different learning steps, batch sizes, different margins in the loss function, choosing different output layers from the original resnet model, different layers added to the end of the resnet, training just the new added layers vs training the whole model. I also tried to use this resnet model without pretrained weights, **the result was still the same, around 0.5 accuracy and 1.0 loss**, no matter what I did. (The input images were preprocessed in the way which was expected for this model with `keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input`)

I didn't do any hard negative mining which may result in slow convergence, but still, 0.5 accuracy in this case (check the function) is random predictions.

So I started thinking maybe I miss something really important here (it's a quite difficult architecture). So please, if you notice something wrong or suspicious in my implementation I'd be really glad for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone'd be interested, rewriting

`y_pred[0]` and `y_pred[1]`

to

`y_pred[:,0,0]` and `y_pred[:,1,0]`

fixed it.

Now the model seems to be training (the loss is decreasing and the accuracy is increasing).

Comment: Is there 'accuracy' for triplet network? Addtionally, if you explain why y_pred[0] changed into y_pred[:,0,0], I would appreciate it.

Comment: @LKM Well, it's not the usual accuracy. This one is telling me how many of the image triplets were classified correctly (two images from the same class, one from a different class). It's telling something at least. Why I did the change I'm not sure about. I tried lots of things and this one worked...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment so I am writing it like this.

I would like to do something similar to what you are doing by using your code.

I am new in CNN and I am not sure how my training data should look like. Would you be willing to share the remainder of your code? I would be very grateful!

Edit:

To answer my own question which may be useful for someone, this is how I did on holidays photos (http://lear.inrialpes.fr/%7Ejegou/data.php) and it works:

```
def get_random_image(img_groups, group_names, gid):
    gname = group_names[gid]
    photos = img_groups[gname]
    pid = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(photos)), size=1)[0]
    pname = photos[pid]
    return gname + pname + ".jpg"

def create_triples(image_dir):
    img_groups = {}
    for img_file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        prefix, suffix = img_file.split(".")
        gid, pid = prefix[0:4], prefix[4:]

        if gid in img_groups.keys():
            img_groups[gid].append(pid)
        else:
            img_groups[gid] = [pid]
    pos_triples, neg_triples = [], []

    for key in img_groups.keys():
        triples = [(key + x[0] + ".jpg", key + x[1] + ".jpg", str(int(key)+3 if int(key)<1495 else int(key)-3)+'01'+'.jpg')
                 for x in itertools.combinations(img_groups[key], 2)]
        pos_triples.extend(triples)

    return pos_triples

def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        margin = K.constant(0.2)
        return K.mean(K.maximum(K.constant(0), K.square(y_pred[:,0,0]) - K.square(y_pred[:,1,0]) + margin))

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred[:,0,0] < y_pred[:,1,0])

def l2Norm(x):
    return  K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)

def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True), K.epsilon()))

triples_data = create_triples(IMAGE_DIR)


dim = 1500
h = 299
w= 299
anchor =np.zeros((dim,h,w,3))
positive =np.zeros((dim,h,w,3))
negative =np.zeros((dim,h,w,3))


for n,val in enumerate(triples_data[0:1500]):
    image_anchor = plt.imread(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, val[0]))
    image_anchor = imresize(image_anchor, (h, w))    
    image_anchor = image_anchor.astype("float32")
    #image_anchor = image_anchor/255.
    image_anchor = keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image_anchor, data_format='channels_last')
    anchor[n] = image_anchor

    image_positive = plt.imread(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, val[1]))
    image_positive = imresize(image_positive, (h, w))
    image_positive = image_positive.astype("float32")
    #image_positive = image_positive/255.
    image_positive = keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image_positive, data_format='channels_last')
    positive[n] = image_positive

    image_negative = plt.imread(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, val[2]))
    image_negative = imresize(image_negative, (h, w))
    image_negative = image_negative.astype("float32")
    #image_negative = image_negative/255.
    image_negative = keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image_negative, data_format='channels_last')
    negative[n] = image_negative

Y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1,2,dim)).T


resnet_input = Input(shape=(h,w,3))
resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top = False, input_tensor=resnet_input)


for layer in resnet_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False  


net = resnet_model.output
net = Flatten(name='flatten')(net) 
net = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='embed')(net)
net = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='embed2')(net)
net = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='embed3')(net)
net = Lambda(l2Norm, output_shape=[128])(net)

base_model = Model(resnet_model.input, net, name='resnet_model')

input_shape=(h,w,3)
input_anchor = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_anchor')
input_positive = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_pos')
input_negative = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_neg')

net_anchor = base_model(input_anchor)
net_positive = base_model(input_positive)
net_negative = base_model(input_negative)

positive_dist = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name='pos_dist')([net_anchor, net_positive])
negative_dist = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name='neg_dist')([net_anchor, net_negative])

stacked_dists = Lambda( 
            lambda vects: K.stack(vects, axis=1),
            name='stacked_dists'
)([positive_dist, negative_dist])


model = Model([input_anchor, input_positive, input_negative], stacked_dists, name='triple_siamese')

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=triplet_loss, metrics=[accuracy])

model.fit([anchor, positive, negative], Y_train, epochs=50,  batch_size=15, validation_split=0.2)

model.save('triplet_loss_resnet50.h5')
```

Comment: why does "K.square(y_pred[0]) - K.square(y_pred[1]) + margin" change into "K.square(y_pred[:,0,0]) - K.square(y_pred[:,1,0]) + margin"? I don't understand. If you can explain your code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: With the code aboe, I sometimes got 0 for loss. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @ 1st question : Because the output shape of the model is (?, 2, 1). You want to substract square of the whole training set for distance between anchor and positive (which is [:, 0, 0]), and square of the whole training set for distance between anchor and negative (which is [:, 1, 0]).

Comment: @ 2nd question: Without further information it is hard for me to say anything. For me this code works. Maybe the training pairs are not properly generated so you are actually comparing distances between, e.g. anchor+positive and anchor+positive?

Comment: What is Y_train in model.fit? What is its shape? If it has been specified that loss=triplet loss, then what is the need of lamba layers. please explain

Comment: Y_train is defined in the code => Y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1,2,dim)).T
NN is supervised machine learning so the syntax expects a training prediction. In this case we don't need it but still have to define a dummy one.
Triplet loss is called because we have 3 values based on which we calculate the error. But ultimately you are calculating distance between anchor and positive - anchor and negative, which are 2 vectors. Lambda is needed because Keras at that time did not have a built in function that can stack vectors, so the workaround is with lambda function.

Comment: @bmorvaj how can we apply prediction using trained triplet loss model?